# Nullreferenceexception when adding point to chart

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, nullreferenceexception

Create chart:

```
    private Chart mainChart;
    private void createChart()
    {
        mainChart = new Chart
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Name = "chart1",
        };
        mainChart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        mainChart.Legends.Add(new Legend());

        mainChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            mainChart.Series.Add(new Series
            {
                Name = "test" + i,
                LegendText = "Test " + (i + 1).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine,
            });
        }
    }
```

Chart property:

```
public Chart chart
{
    get
    {
        return mainChart;
    }
    set
    {
        mainChart = value;
        Form activeChild = FormAlreadyLoaded("Child_Chart");
        if (activeChild != null)
        {
            Chart frmchart = activeChild.Controls.Find("chart1", true).FirstOrDefault() as Chart;
            frmchart = mainChart;
        }
    }
}
```

FormAlreadyLoaded method:

```
private Form FormAlreadyLoaded(string formName)
{
    foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
        if (frm.Name.Equals(formName))
            return frm;
    return null;
}
```

Child_Chart is a simple form with this in the "Load" method:

```
MainForm parent = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
this.Controls.Add(parent.chart);
```

Add to chart (where the error happens)

```
chart.Series[i].Points.AddXY(value1,value2);
```

Exception text:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.get_Series()
   at Oasis.MainForm.<>c__DisplayClass13.<ProcessSerial>b__11() in MainForm.cs:line 355
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
```

More information:

createChart() is the first thing called in the load event of the main form.

The line of code that causes the error is inside a

```
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
```

in the DataRecieved event of a serialPort

Local values of 'mainChart' after the error appears i.imgur.com/LZSY3Iw.png

All this code works fine, until I close "Child_Chart".

Answer (score 0):

As Points property of series[i] is probably a non primitive type, you need to initialize it with its constructor using the 'new' keyword

Comment: I added more information to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain `chart` isn't what's null? I don't see where `CreateChart()` gets called, and I don't see anywhere else that private field `mainChart` is instantiated.

Aside from that, you need to break at the error and look to see which is the null reference. It could be `chart`, `chart.Series`, or `chart.Series[i]`, and so on through the entire statement.

Comment: I added more information to the main post.